# Show IP camera using c# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, camera, ip-camera, surveillance

i'm developing software to display ip camera "Acti", i tried to use axnvUnifiedControl but i cannot find any information about it.

my goal is to connect to the camera using IP, username, and password and display the camera image in windows form.

i'm using c# .net 4.0

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? Or at leastdoing stuff like FINDING A LINK TO THE MANUFACTURER TO POST HERE? ACTI is not a camera, btw., it is a Company, so? I am trying to use software type "Microsoft", does not work, help? A LOT more information is needed.

Comment: Actually I tried to download the SDK but the after filling the form the link is down, so i tried to investigate it by myself so i found this OCX, i tried also to contact them to send me the SDK, they called me and told me they will contact me again to send it to me, but they didn't, Thanks anyway. I solved the prob, i'm going to answer the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following code snippet:

- First you should reference the OCX in your toolbox, and drag it to your form. but i tried to use it in design mode, but the VS is hang and force close.

  ```
  camMedia.MediaSource = CameraIP;    
  camMedia.MediaUsername = UserName;  
  camMedia.MediaPassword = Password;    
  camMedia.HttpPort = HttpPort;//80    
  camMedia.RegisterPort = RegisterPort;//6000    
  camMedia.ControlPort = ControlPort;//6001    
  camMedia.StreamingPort = StreamingPort;//6002    
  camMedia.Connect(0);
  ```

where the `camMedia` is the OCX object name.

Answer (score 0):

[ACTi](http://www.acti.com/product/index.asp) has quite a wide range of cameras, and they do not share uniform API. You have to look for documentation for your model of interest and check the vendor's sample code and SDKs. The cameras also have some support for well known protocols, such as `RTSP` and `M-JPEG over HTTP` so you can leverage certain libraries to visualize the feed, but again you will need documentation, specification and SDKs to find out the essential information.